# Can't get extensions to work in VS 2010 Professional - should I reinstall?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx

I've had this problem for a while, and no one I've talked to on the various Microsoft boards I've visited has been able to help me.

I have a copy of VS 2010 Professional installed on my laptop.  It works pretty well, but extensions simply don't work.  I've tried installing and running several of them, but all that happens is my program becomes unstable, to the point of crashing every few minutes.  I've tried repairing my install, both as a normal user and as an administrator, but the problem remains.

I can access the Extension Manager through Tools->Extension Manager.  However, I cannot go to Tools->Options->Extension Manager as that option doesn't exist for me in the left hand pane.

I've tried Resetting the defaults in the Import/Export Manager, but no luck.  I've also tried several command line commands, but, again, no dice.

I'm just wondering if

- This kind of thing has happened to
  anyone else
- If there's a way to
  fix it without reinstalling
- If
  not, if there are steps I can take
  during the reinstall to ensure things
  are installed properly.

For completeness' sake, my copy of VS was obtained through the Website Spark program.  My laptop stats are:

- Windows 7 Home Premium
- Intel i7
- 4 GB RAM
- 500 GB HDD

Should be more than enough to handle the program and extensions, correct?

I'd really like to at least get TortoiseSVN working.

**EDIT:** It's been a while since I wrote this question, but the problem remains.  Like I wrote in a comment below, the VS2010 SDK fails with a 'Missing Component' error.  I've tried just about everything I can think of:

- Uninstall/reinstall
- Repair from the .iso
- Just about every command line flag I've read about
- Running it as administrator

Nothing has fixed it.

I have a couple screenshots showing that 'Extensions' isn't even an option in 'Tools'->'Options' (even though the *Extension Manager* is available... weird), and a couple of log files (installation log and my last startup/activity log), but I'm not sure who to show them to.  The official Microsoft forums have been less than helpful.

So, what can I do?  Who can I show my files to?  Is there anyone at Microsoft who won't give me the same scripted answers?

Comment: Man, I feel sorry for you in this situation. +1 to you for me feeling bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't normally answer my own questions, but I found the problem.  One of the security programs I had installed on my machine - PC Tools' Threatfire - was the cause of the problem.  I've informed Microsoft of this, and will also inform PC Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Something to try - download the Visual Studio SDK (you can get it from www.visualstudiogallery.com) and then launch the Experimental Instance (there's an item in the start menu under the SDK.) That uses different settings, registry keys, magic folders etc. If the Experimental Instance can run extensions then you will get some clues about what's happening to your install.

Comment: Getting a "Cannot find one or more components.  Please reinstall the application."  Guessing my current install is borked.

Answer (score 0):

I tnink you should try to install this version of your visual studio on newly installed clean system to exclude possible conflicts of software installed, system options etc.

Answer (score -1):

It definitely sounds like a problem with your installation (almost like some core piece of VS was corrupted). You should try running Visual Studio setup and looking for the options to repair your installation.

Comment: Can you launch Visual Studio in safe mode? From a "Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt", run "devenv /safemode /log". The /log command will also produce an ActivityLog.xml file under %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 that may highlight any problems.